# Laravel relationship between three tables

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, model

I have 3 tables:

- Events
- Ages
- Books

Which I was relating them in the following way:

- ages

  - id
  - name
- books

  - id
  - title
- age_book

  - id
  - age_id
  - book_id
- events

  - id
  - name
- event_age

  - id
  - event_id
  - age_id
- event_age_book

  - event_age_id
  - book_id

Basically, a book can have many ages, an age can have many books, an event can have many ages, an event age can have many books.

My Event Model looks like this and works fine to get all event ages

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    public function ages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Age::class, 'event_age');
    }
}
```

Age Model:

```php
class Age extends Model
{
    public function books(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Book::class)
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Book Model

```php
class Book extends Model
{
    public function ages(): BelongsToMany
    {
         return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Age::class, 'book_age', 'book_id','age_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Im having trouble figuring out how to get all edition age books, is it possible to do it on the Event model?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out why you have the last table event_age_book seems redundant and prone to make your life unnecessarily complicated.  Perhaps you could explain why you need that last table?

Comment: @J.A.Streich i need the event_age_book because an event_age will only have a few selected books from that age, not all books associated with that age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's Review The Relationships

Seems you should only need 3 models, and 5 tables.

- Books Belong to Ages
- Events Belong to Ages
- Ages Belongs to Books
- Ages Belongs to Events

Your other models are alright, but your age model is missing a relationship to Event:

```
class Age extends Model
{
    public function books(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class)
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function events(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Events::class,'event_age')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

That would allow:

```
$books->ages;
$events->ages;
$ages->book;
$ages->events;
```

And chaining...

```
$books = collect();
foreach($event->ages as $age){
    $books->merge($ages->books);
}
$books->unique();
```

### Books and Events

So, I gon't think you want `age_event_book`s.  I think what you really want is:

- Events belong to Books
- Books belong to Events

such that

```
book_events
- id
- book_id
- event_id
- age_id
```

And you'd have in book:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Event')
       ->withTimestamps()
       ->withPivot('age_id');
}
```

And in event:

```
public function books()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book')->withTimestamps()
      ->withPiviot('age_id')->groupBy('age_id');
}
```

Giving you:

```
$event->books
$book->events
```

#### On the Front End

> [O]n the frontend i'll need to get the most recent event and group books by age and books can belong to more than one age

```
$event = Event::latest();
$books = $event->books();
```

Then on the blade

```
@foreach($books as $age_id => $books)
    <h4>{{Age::find($age_id)->name}}</h4>
    @foreach($books as $book)
       <div>$book->name</div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

#### Helpful Tip

You are supplying the relation table, which you have to do because you didn't follow the naming convention for joining tables.  The convention is that the classes being joined should be listed alphabetically.  So `age_event` instead of `event_age`.

Comment: I need the age_event_book because an age_event will only have a few selected books, not all books associated with that age. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Does that have to be an age_event has....  (meaning another model and bunch more relationships) or is it than an event has many books.

Comment: An event having many books doesn't really matter, just the event age having many books and the event having many ages, because on the frontend i'll need to get the most recent  event and group books by age and books can belong to more than one age.

Comment: I don't think is possible, because for event age i want to select only a few books from that age and a book selected can also be selected for another age on the same event.

Comment: Edited.  It's a rough sketch.  It can be optimized more, but it can get you what the imgur shows.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but i don't think it works because it will return all books selected for an event  for every age in that event even if i did not select a book for a certain age for that event.

Comment: Let's say we have book1, book2, book3 and book4 and age 10 and age 13.  For Age 10 we have book1, book2 and book3 and for Age 13 we have book1 and book4. I must be able to say that for an Event on Age 10 i'll have Book 1 and Book3 and for Age 13 i'll only have book4. You code also returns book1  for Age 13 even though it was not selected for that event.

Comment: Sorry.  That should fix that. Much better and shorter.